# Thickness to windows

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, bmesh

I have been making a plane in blender for some time now and the one thing I cannot get around is adding thickness to windows on a plane. I have been making the plane using a cylinder and are NOT going to use sub surf to add a smoothing effect. Instead I am using the shade as smooth option. I am using the solidify modifier to add the thickness to the windows and then using boolean to cut out the shapes of the window. I have good sources that tell me it is possible to use boolean and still get good results. One the boolean as applied it completely messes up the surface of the cylinder. I have one refrence image as to what I would like the end result to be like.[image]

Comment: Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81131/boolean-modifier-not-working-with-solidify-modifier?rq=1

Comment: The only way I've been able to do this without ugly streaks on the fuselage is to leave the geometry alone altogether and use 'inviso' masked windows instead.  

Take a look at these two videos and judge for yourself if this is what you're after.   The results whilst suiting my own purposes, may not suit your own, particularly if for a 3D model that's to come under closer scrunity.  The links - https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lm9189tug5r08a/InvisoPortholes.mp4?dl=0   and the 2nd - https://www.dropbox.com/s/kd3p3ytrpl5lpz9/Rimmed.mp4?dl=0